# How to get values from an array and store it into separate variables using java?

Tags: java

I have four years stored inside this array at index 0. I would like to extract this data and store it inside individual variables, For instance, dateParts array consist of 2020,2019,2018,2017.How would i go about extracting that data and storing it into my year variables. I have tried the typical `String year2020 = years[0], year2019 = [1];` but this will cause an out of bound error because all four years are stored in the 0 Index. They are NOT separate indexes.

```
String [] dateParts = dates.split("-");
firstyear = dateParts[0];

String year2020, year2019 year2018, year2017;
```

Comment: What's the contents of `dates`?

Comment: JSON data that got converted to string.

Comment: I meant, what’s the literal contents of `dates`? If we have the exact string we’re more likely to be able to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed number of different variable you want to store your elements into, I'm afraid you'll have to do it manually as such:

```
year2020 = dateParts[0];
year2019 = dateParts[1];
year2018 = dateParts[2];
year2017 = dateParts[3];
```

Your question isn't clear, though and the above solution assumes `2020,2019,2018` and `2017` are individual elements in the `dateParts` array.

If you're saying `"2020,2019,2018,2017"` is one string stored in `dataParts[0]` and you'd like to extract them individually, you could achieve this using the `String.split()` method with `","` as delimiter.

```
String years[] = dateParts[0].split(",");

year2020 = years[0];
year2019 = years[1];
year2018 = years[2];
year2017 = years[3];
```

EDIT:

Based on edited question:

```
String years[] = firstyear.split(",");

year2020 = years[0];
year2019 = years[1];
year2018 = years[2];
year2017 = years[3];
```

Comment: Yes  "2020,2019,2018,2017" is one string stored in dataParts[0] and i would like to extract them individually. I tried the code you provided but it caused  an out of bound error. 0 index contains all 4 years. That's why. What your're saying would work if the 4 year were stored in separate  indexes but they are not. They're all stored under the 0 Index.

Comment: This is the error btw.      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: Did you use the second code? Use only that one for your solution.

Comment: If this answer helped, please consider marking it as such. If not, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Try that. If it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still yields an error. As mentioned index 1, 2, 3 does not exist because all the data is stored at the 0 index.  If i do years2020 = years[0]; and try to print the data out of this value. All 4 years get displayed. But i would like to extract that data and store it into separate  string variables .Index 1,2,3 will cause an out of bound error.

Comment: It works on my system. I'm not sure what you're doing exactly. Send me your full code otherwise.